# Redirect a user to an URL if expirationDate in localStorage is expired (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display some Twitch datas using Twitch API on my website using React/Node,

I succeeded to display these datas, but at some time the expirationDate property of the token response becomes expired (expirationDate that I chose to put in my localStorage), and the datas don't display anymore,

So, I would need something like this

```
    if (
      !localStorage.getItem("expirationDate") ||
      localStorage.getItem("expirationDate") < new Date().getTime()
    ) {
      window.location.href = process.env.REACT_APP_TWITCH_ENDPOINT;
    }
```

Here's my full code

```
  useEffect(() => {
    authenticate();
  }, []);

  function authenticate() {
    if (
      !localStorage.getItem("expirationDate") ||
      localStorage.getItem("expirationDate") < new Date().getTime()
    ) {
      window.location.href = process.env.REACT_APP_TWITCH_ENDPOINT;
    }

    getModerators(
      new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get("code") ||
        localStorage.getItem("code"),
      localStorage.getItem("accessToken") || "",
      localStorage.getItem("expirationDate") || ""
    );
  }

  function getModerators(code, accessToken, expirationDate) {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/getModerators", {
        code,
        accessToken,
        expirationDate,
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        localStorage.setItem("expirationDate", response.data.expirationDate);
        localStorage.setItem("accessToken", response.data.accessToken);
        localStorage.setItem(
          "code",
          new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get("code") ||
            localStorage.getItem("code")
        );
        history.push("/");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("error ", error);
      });
  }
```

**But by doing this, I get in an infinite redirection to the URL...**

**How can I redirect the user to the URL above if the expirationDate timestamp in localStorage is expired or not defined without getting in an infinite redirection ? Thanks**

Comment: Seems the only way to stop the infinite redirection in your scenario is to update `expirationDate` in localStorage to some future date or some non numeric value, thus it'll not fall into that if block.

Comment: I struggle to find a way to redirect the user if the expirationDate is expired, because it's supposed to redirect directly when the user arrives on the website.